# Policy File Check closes socket

Tags: apache-flex, sockets, cross-domain-policy

I have created a flex app that uses sockets. I published the flex app in a web application that runs on glassfish server. 
Now from that flex app i create a socket connection to a C# server and start sending/receiving data.
The problem is that after i create the socket connection to C# server the flex app first checks the policy file, and after it get's it, it closes the socket, without keep the connection alive.

This is my C# server:

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("172.17.41.211"), 12345);
TcpClient tcpclient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

Socket client = tcpclient.Client;
while (client.Available > 0)
{
   int bytes = 0;
   byte[] m_aBuffer = new byte[1024];
   bytes = client.Receive(m_aBuffer, m_aBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
   String str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_aBuffer, 0, bytes);
   if (str.StartsWith("<policy-file-request/>"))
   {
      sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain=\"172.17.41.211\" to-ports=\"12345\"/></cross-domain-policy>\0");
      client.Send(sendBytes);
   }
}

while (client.Connected)
{
   Thread.Sleep(200);
   sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("message to client");
   client.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
}
```

Now the flex client looks like:

```
private var socket:Socket = new Socket();
socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onData);
socket.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandler);
...
socket.connect("172.17.41.211", 12345);    
...
```

Now after i create the connection and it gets the policy from server it closes this socket, so to be able to use this connection i have to call again

```
socket.connect("172.17.41.211", 12345));
```

After i do this, i can use normally the connection.

Can someone suggest why this happens and maybe is possible to not have closed the connection ?

Comment: Can I ask *why* you're using a socket server in the first place?  Is there a very specific reason or you just want a connection to your server?  Because there are easier and better ways to connect client to server than creating your own socket since there are a lot of already create, very well know and proven standards out there.

Comment: Yes, this is something that we need to communicate with the server in a specific way.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive?  There could very well be a better alternative.

Comment: We have a C# server with a custom protocol, this server runs for a while and it works fine. Now i need a client that connects to that server and receive messages in a specific format(ASCII + byte arrays, byte arrays are audio streams sent from the server like pcm raw data). When i receive message i decode it and see what to do next with it. I cannot change the server side(i know only the communication protocol), but i need the client to communicate with this server. This why i created a socket connection to a specific port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't send the policy file through the socket itself.  It needs to be on a different channel.  For instance, if you connect to some ip/port, by default flash will try to connect to the same ip but on port 843 and look for the master policy file.

You can also set it manually using `Security.loadPolicyFile(someURL)`.  [More information can be found here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c60.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c63).

Comment: but this means that i have to create a separate thread that will listen on port 843 ? But aren't there any other solutions ?

Comment: I believe you can specify an http server for the policy file, but don't take my word on it.  Look at the documentation.

Comment: That's the main problem, that what i concluded from the documentation is that i will have to create a separate thread for handling the request of the policy data. But i tought that i can do that witout creating this separate thread.

Comment: You could just specify a url and use a webserver: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#loadPolicyFile()

Comment: For this i need to create a web server on the server side, but i cannot do that, or it will imply a lot of work, because the server runs on a mobile device(WINCE5.0). This why the most reasonable solution will be to create a new thread on the socket 843.